# C# Accessing Item Properties when looping through generic LinkedList<T>

Tags: c#, linked-list

I am trying to do something I thought would have been extremely simple. But it is not working and I cannot figure out why. I am also confused why I have searched so much and cannot find an example of looping through a generic linkedlist and accessing the properties of the objects contained in the linkedlist. It seems like this would be so basic there'd be a ton of examples.

I have a generic linked list defined as a private field in my class with a corresponding public property.

```
    private LinkedList<MyObject> _genericLinkedListOfMyObjects;
```

I have a method in my class that I would like to use to iterate through the items of the linked list, and access the values of the properties of the items.

MyObject is a basic class with properties:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string property1 { get; set; }
    public string property2 { get; set; }
}
```

None of the following work:

```
foreach (MyObject item in genericLinkedListOfMyObjects)
{
    item.property1; //NOPE!
}
```

This results in complier error "'MyObject' does not contain a definition of 'property1' and no accessible extension method 'property1' accepting a first argument of type 'MyObject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)?"

Nor

```
LinkedListNode<MyObject> current = genericLinkedListOfMyObjects.First;
while (current !=null)
{
    current.Value.property1; //NOPE!
}
```

This results in complier error "'MyObject' does not contain a definition of 'property1' and no accessible extension method 'property1' accepting a first argument of type 'MyObject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)?"

Nor

```
foreach (var item in genericLinkedListOfMyObjects)
{
    MyObject myObj = item as MyObject; //NOPE!  
}
```

This results in compile error "The type parameter 'MyObject' cannot be used with the 'as' operator because it does not have a class type constraint nor a 'class' constraint.

How can I access the value of property1 for an item in the generic linked list as I am looping through? Thank you in advance.

Comment: _"None of the following work"_ Any errors? Explain why they don't work?

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "not working"? Does it not compile? Does it compile, but crash with a null reference exception? I don't think the error message is literally "NOPE!". Funny if it were, though.

Comment: Please see updated question. I added what the compiler error says.

Comment: The errors you're getting sound like you've defined MyObject in a separate file/namespace and haven't imported it with a `using` statement. Are you sure the code you're iterating in even knows what a `MyObject` is?

Comment: It is most definitely in the same namespace. It is in the same file too (although I wouldn't think that would make a difference if the namespace was the same).

Comment: @D.M. Thanks for the update. You're going to have to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's possible you have *two* "MyObject" (whatever the real name is) classes defined in two different namespaces. But it's not a productive use of anybody's time for us to sit here throwing guesses at you. If `MyObject` is defined as you say, only one class, same namespace, etc., your code should absolutely work with zero issues. I've done it 20 times a day for a decade. So there's something non-obvious here.

Comment: @D.M. yeah different files wouldn't matter if it's the same namespace. Without the full code in its original layout, it's going to be hard to figure out the problem - I've done a quick implementation of what _I think_ you're showing (similar to what Soaking did in his answer) and I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: OK, I'll draft up new solution (that only includes this specific issue) and post the full code example.

Comment: @D.M. You don't by chance have a `LinkedList<BaseClass>`, but `property1` etc. actually belongs to some *subclass* of `BaseClass`? The last example in your question seems to rule that out, but just want to be sure.

Comment: I will have to look further, but whatever is going on, the heart of my question was answered about accessing properties of an item in a generic linked list so I posted the full code example as an answer to my own question. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. Your question has a low quality. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, your development environment and the data structures, as well as to share more code (no screenshot), images or sketches of the screen, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, consider reading the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)*.

Comment: @DM The code compiles if you add an assignment in the foreach loops... and if you remove the underscore in the declaration... And you don't assign and populate the list. The question is loss of time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, @Ed you were right something else is going on. I will work on figuring out what that is. But I am comforted to know that it is something with namespaces rather than something unexpected  with LinkedLists.

So yes the following works just fine. Thanks for pointing out possible sources of the problem and that you thought the code I had ought to work fine.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestLinkedList1
{
    public class TestClass
    {

        public void DoStuff()
        {
            MyObject myobj1 = new MyObject();
            MyObject myobj2 = new MyObject();

            myobj1.property1 = "Foo";
            myobj2.property1 = "Bar";

            LinkedList<MyObject> genericLinkedListofMyObjects = new LinkedList<MyObject>();

            genericLinkedListofMyObjects.AddFirst(myobj1);
            genericLinkedListofMyObjects.AddFirst(myobj2);

            foreach (var item in genericLinkedListofMyObjects)
            {
                string mystring = item.property1; //WORKS!
            }

        }

    }

    public class MyObject
    {
        public string property1 { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code that you pasted was not complete so multiple things could be a problem with the code above. I can just assume a couple of them:

```
while (current !=null)
{
    current.Value.property1; //NOPE!
}
```

You will get this error:
Only assignemt, call, increment, decrement, await and new object expression can be used as a statement.

So you have to do something with the current.Value.property1 either assign it to some variable, call another method, increment and etc...

Also here you have:

```
foreach (MyObject item in genericLinkedListOfMyObjects)
```

but above your variable is called with prefix "_". It is hard to tell based on the code you have pasted here. So either you have 2 fields or your loop shoud use _genericLinkedListOfMyObjects as declared here:

```
private LinkedList<MyObject> _genericLinkedListOfMyObjects;
```

**Code sample:**

Here is a small Console app where you can see how to work with LinkedList based your attempts.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TestLinkedList
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = new TestLinkedList();
            test.Test1();
            Console.WriteLine();
            test.Test2();
            Console.WriteLine();
            test.Test3();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Done!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class MyObject
    {
        public string property1 { get; set; }
        public string property2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestLinkedList
    {
        private LinkedList<MyObject> _genericLinkedListOfMyObjects; 

        public void Test1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test1");
            _genericLinkedListOfMyObjects = new LinkedList<MyObject>();
            _genericLinkedListOfMyObjects.AddFirst(new MyObject{ property1="Prop1 Test1", property2="Prop2 Test1" });
            _genericLinkedListOfMyObjects.AddFirst(new MyObject{ property1="Prop1 Test2", property2="Prop2 Test2" });

            foreach (MyObject item in _genericLinkedListOfMyObjects)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.property1);
                Console.WriteLine(item.property2);
            }
        }

        public void Test2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test2");
            _genericLinkedListOfMyObjects = new LinkedList<MyObject>();
            _genericLinkedListOfMyObjects.AddFirst(new MyObject{ property1="Prop1 Test1", property2="Prop2 Test1" });
            _genericLinkedListOfMyObjects.AddFirst(new MyObject{ property1="Prop1 Test2", property2="Prop2 Test2" });

            LinkedListNode<MyObject> current = _genericLinkedListOfMyObjects.First;
            while (current !=null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(current.Value.property1);
                Console.WriteLine(current.Value.property2);
                current = current.Next;
            }
        }

        public void Test3()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Test3");
            _genericLinkedListOfMyObjects = new LinkedList<MyObject>();
            _genericLinkedListOfMyObjects.AddFirst(new MyObject{ property1="Prop1 Test1", property2="Prop2 Test1" });
            _genericLinkedListOfMyObjects.AddFirst(new MyObject{ property1="Prop1 Test2", property2="Prop2 Test2" });

            LinkedListNode<MyObject> current = _genericLinkedListOfMyObjects.First;
            foreach (var item in _genericLinkedListOfMyObjects)
            {
                MyObject myObj = item as MyObject; //NOPE!
                Console.WriteLine(myObj.property1);
                Console.WriteLine(myObj.property2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why down vote? I posted the answer based on your inititian question without the edit and without the error messages.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, I didn't down vote (in fact I'm new to Stack Overflow and haven't earned enough points to vote yet).